# How to properly self-execute a closure

Tags: javascript

I'm studying closures and the global scope, and am confused about when to use }()) vs. })().  It seems that I've lucked upon a situation where it doesn't matter which one I use.

```
(function() {

    var myFunction = (function() {
        var i=100;
        return function() {
            return i++;
        }
    }());
    var X = myFunction();
    console.log(X);
    X = myFunction();
    console.log(X);

})();
```

Comment: You don't have a description of what the actual problem is (why it doesn't matter?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(function () { return 1; });` doesn't evaluate the function. `("append" + " us")` does evaluate the strings.

So yeah, in this case it doesn't matter because:

```
var myFunction = (function() {
    var i=100;
    return function() {
        return i++;
    }
}());
```

evaluates to `(function() { return i++; }` which just returns the anonymous function.

and:

```
var myFunction = (function() {
  var i=100;
    return function() {
      return i++;
    }
})();
```

evaluates myFunction after the braces. And.. just returns the anonymous function. Woh.

Answer (score 2):

Its how expressions work in JS.

The following all work because the `+`,`-`,`(`,`~`... designate the beginning of an expression.

```
!function(){}()
~function(){}()
+function(){}()
-function(){}()
(function(){})()
(function(){}())
```

Comment: Lime: I think you should tell him, "It actually doesn't matter which one you use."  I sure Crockford has a preference, but I doubt it makes any practical difference.